# Mongo aggregate move embedded document to collection where id equals

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, flask

Good day, noble mongoDB users.
I have a problem with moving one embedded document on the document level with a certain condition.

This query:

```
db.products_oil.aggregate([
{
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': 'brands',
                    'localField': 'brand_id',
                    'foreignField': '_id',
                    'as': 'brand'
                }
            },
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': 'categories',
                    'localField': 'category_id',
                    'foreignField': '_id',
                    'as': 'category'
                }
            },
            {'$unwind': "$brand"},
            {'$unwind': "$category"},
            {
                '$sort': {
                    'position': 1
                }
            }
]).pretty()
```

gives me such structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f08a990d4a40117fbe1e679"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-10T20:46:56.282Z"),
    "brand_id" : ObjectId("5ef51c165ff59a574439fd0b"),
    "category_id" : ObjectId("5efa20238a909a3d4c52110a"),
    "subCategory_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc82480962e22ae096d"),
    "position" : 2,
    "active" : 1,
    "productName" : "qwe",
    "productDescription" : "<p>asd</p>",
    "productSpec" : "<p>qwe</p>",
    "productImgPath" : "files/1594403209__me.jpg",
    "productPdf1Path" : "files/pdf/1594403212__20191120-948-cunncj-pdf.pdf",
    "productPdf2Path" : "files/pdf/1594403214__20191120-948-cunncj-pdf.pdf",
    "brand" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef51c165ff59a574439fd0b"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-26T00:50:14.207Z"),
        "position" : 3,
        "active" : 1,
        "brandImgPath" : "files/1593121813__5.png",
        "brandName" : "xcvxz"
    },
    "category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5efa20238a909a3d4c52110a"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:08:51.035Z"),
        "position" : 2,
        "active" : 1,
        "categoryType" : 1,
        "categoryName" : "dccccccccc",
        "categoryDescription" : "<p>cccccccccccccccccc</p>",
        "subCategories" : [ 
            {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc12480962e22ae0969"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:58:25.894Z"),
                "position" : 3,
                "active" : 1,
                "subCategoryName" : "sscdc",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>csdcsdcsdc</p>"
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc82480962e22ae096d"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:58:32.481Z"),
                "position" : 2,
                "active" : 1,
                "subCategoryName" : "safasdfasdf",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>asfvt3333</p>"
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efcb3e624f3a0d6351f9b69"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-01T19:03:50.189Z"),
                "position" : 1,
                "active" : 0,
                "subCategoryName" : "asd",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>asd</p>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to put category.subCategories object as "subcategory" to most upper level (level of collection itself) where
category.subCategories.sub_id === subCategory_id

to have some kind of:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f08a990d4a40117fbe1e679"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-10T20:46:56.282Z"),
    "brand_id" : ObjectId("5ef51c165ff59a574439fd0b"),
    "category_id" : ObjectId("5efa20238a909a3d4c52110a"),
    "subCategory_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc82480962e22ae096d"),
    "position" : 2,
    "active" : 1,
    "productName" : "qwe",
    "productDescription" : "<p>asd</p>",
    "productSpec" : "<p>qwe</p>",
    "productImgPath" : "files/1594403209__me.jpg",
    "productPdf1Path" : "files/pdf/1594403212__20191120-948-cunncj-pdf.pdf",
    "productPdf2Path" : "files/pdf/1594403214__20191120-948-cunncj-pdf.pdf",
    "brand" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef51c165ff59a574439fd0b"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-26T00:50:14.207Z"),
        "position" : 3,
        "active" : 1,
        "brandImgPath" : "files/1593121813__5.png",
        "brandName" : "xcvxz"
    },
    "category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5efa20238a909a3d4c52110a"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:08:51.035Z"),
        "position" : 2,
        "active" : 1,
        "categoryType" : 1,
        "categoryName" : "dccccccccc",
        "categoryDescription" : "<p>cccccccccccccccccc</p>",
        "subCategories" : [ 
            {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc12480962e22ae0969"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:58:25.894Z"),
                "position" : 3,
                "active" : 1,
                "subCategoryName" : "sscdc",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>csdcsdcsdc</p>"
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc82480962e22ae096d"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:58:32.481Z"),
                "position" : 2,
                "active" : 1,
                "subCategoryName" : "safasdfasdf",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>asfvt3333</p>"
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efcb3e624f3a0d6351f9b69"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-01T19:03:50.189Z"),
                "position" : 1,
                "active" : 0,
                "subCategoryName" : "asd",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>asd</p>"
            }
        ]
    },
    "subcategory" : {
                "sub_id" : ObjectId("5efa2bc82480962e22ae096d"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-29T20:58:32.481Z"),
                "position" : 2,
                "active" : 1,
                "subCategoryName" : "safasdfasdf",
                "subCategoryDescription" : "<p>asfvt3333</p>"
    }, 

}
```

Got completely messed with unwinds, groups and projects :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

```
{
  $addFields: {
    subcategory: {
      $reduce: {
        input: "$category.subCategories",
        initialValue: null, // default value in case subcategory is not found
        in: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.sub_id", "$subCategory_id"] }, "$$this", "$$value"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$filter` and `$addFields` should do that for you:

```
  {$addFields:{
    subcategory:{
      $arrayElemAt: [
        {$filter:{
           input: "$category.subCategories",
           cond: {$eq:[ "$$this.sub_id", "$subCategory_id" ]}
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
```

Comment: This is neat and clean solution ***is working!*** Appreciate your time, sir!